# Formik: calling validateField() on nested field throws error "can't access property "validate", fieldRegistry.current[name] is undefined"

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using React with Formik v `^2.2.5"`

Here is a link to a code snippet in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-vqwnm3?file=/index.js

The important parts:

Note the default values. `facebook` is nested within `socialMedia`:

```
  initialValues={{ email: "", socialMedia: { facebook: "" } }}
  validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email().required("Required"),
    socialMedia: Yup.object().shape({
      facebook: Yup.string(),
      gmail: Yup.string()
    })
  })}
```

For the actual input, note the id is `socialMedia.facebook` (using the nested value). and the onBlur calls `validateField("socialMedia.facebook")` :

```
        <input
          id="socialMedia.facebook"
          name="facebook"
          value={values.socialMedia.facebook}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={() => {
            validateField("socialMedia.facebook");
            setFieldTouched("socialMedia.facebook");
          }}
          className={
            errors.socialMedia?.facebook && touched.socialMedia?.facebook
              ? "text-input error"
              : "text-input"
          }
        />
```

When you onblur from the `facebook` field, it throws an error
`can't access property "validate", fieldRegistry.current[name] is undefined`

But I would expect for there to be no error and the field is properly validated.

Note: `setFieldTouched("socialMedia.facebook");` does indeed work and sets the proper touch field in the formik object.

Answer (score 2):

You must define name props. Because formik recognizes the field values by name.
[image]

Comment: I added the name prop like so ```name="socialMedia.facebook"``` and I am still getting the same error. I've edited the sandbox to reflect that change.

Comment: I am not sure why you need to call the `validateField`, `setFieldTouched` functions. Please check like this.
onBlur={handleBlur}